# BigDecimal not present when resolving type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I'm "up the middle" Spring Boot 2.5.4 with graphql-java-16.2 brought in via some `org.springframework.experimental/graphql-spring-boot-starter` dependency. The GraphQL Java Documentation suggests that I can just BigDecimal something up in my Schema: https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v16/scalars/

```
...
type TemplateLineItemAction {
    type: String!
    quantity: BigDecimal!
}
...
```

The runtime begs to differ. The operative portion of the giant stacktrace is...

```
...SchemaProblem{errors=[The field type 'BigDecimal' is not present when resolving type 'TemplateLineItemAction' [@5:1]]}...
```

The giant stacktrace is...

```
2021-08-19 14:38:34.609 ERROR 85256 --- [  restartedMain] g.springframework.boot.SpringApplication:  Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'routerFunctionMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlRouterFunction' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQlRouterFunction' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlHttpHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQlHttpHandler' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webGraphQlHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webGraphQlHandler' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlServiceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQlService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.graphql.execution.GraphQlSource]: Factory method 'graphQlSource' threw exception; nested exception is SchemaProblem{errors=[The field type 'BigDecimal' is not present when resolving type 'TemplateLineItemAction' [@5:1]]}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at aero.blue.ems.boa.Application.main(Application.java:10)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlRouterFunction' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQlRouterFunction' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlHttpHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQlHttpHandler' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webGraphQlHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webGraphQlHandler' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlServiceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQlService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.graphql.execution.GraphQlSource]: Factory method 'graphQlSource' threw exception; nested exception is SchemaProblem{errors=[The field type 'BigDecimal' is not present when resolving type 'TemplateLineItemAction' [@5:1]]}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.support.RouterFunctionMapping.initRouterFunction(RouterFunctionMapping.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.support.RouterFunctionMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RouterFunctionMapping.java:138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlHttpHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQlHttpHandler' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webGraphQlHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webGraphQlHandler' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlServiceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQlService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.graphql.execution.GraphQlSource]: Factory method 'graphQlSource' threw exception; nested exception is SchemaProblem{errors=[The field type 'BigDecimal' is not present when resolving type 'TemplateLineItemAction' [@5:1]]}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webGraphQlHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webGraphQlHandler' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlServiceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQlService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.graphql.execution.GraphQlSource]: Factory method 'graphQlSource' threw exception; nested exception is SchemaProblem{errors=[The field type 'BigDecimal' is not present when resolving type 'TemplateLineItemAction' [@5:1]]}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlServiceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQlService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.graphql.execution.GraphQlSource]: Factory method 'graphQlSource' threw exception; nested exception is SchemaProblem{errors=[The field type 'BigDecimal' is not present when resolving type 'TemplateLineItemAction' [@5:1]]}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/graphql/boot/GraphQlAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.graphql.execution.GraphQlSource]: Factory method 'graphQlSource' threw exception; nested exception is SchemaProblem{errors=[The field type 'BigDecimal' is not present when resolving type 'TemplateLineItemAction' [@5:1]]}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.graphql.execution.GraphQlSource]: Factory method 'graphQlSource' threw exception; nested exception is SchemaProblem{errors=[The field type 'BigDecimal' is not present when resolving type 'TemplateLineItemAction' [@5:1]]}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 93 common frames omitted
Caused by: graphql.schema.idl.errors.SchemaProblem: errors=[The field type 'BigDecimal' is not present when resolving type 'TemplateLineItemAction' [@5:1]]
    at graphql.schema.idl.SchemaGenerator.makeExecutableSchema(SchemaGenerator.java:74)
    at graphql.schema.idl.SchemaGenerator.makeExecutableSchema(SchemaGenerator.java:52)
    at org.springframework.graphql.execution.DefaultGraphQlSourceBuilder.build(DefaultGraphQlSourceBuilder.java:109)
    at org.springframework.graphql.boot.GraphQlAutoConfiguration.graphQlSource(GraphQlAutoConfiguration.java:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 94 common frames omitted
```

I tried just adding `scalar BigDecimal` to the schema.graphqls file to no avail; same stacktrace.

The pom.xml is like...

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Note the `graphql-spring-boot-starter` starter comes by way of Spring (`org.springframework.experimental/graphql-spring-boot-starter`), not `com.graphql-java/graphiql-spring-boot-starter`, which is where many google results point me. It really shouldn't matter, that BigDecimal mapping is *supposed* to be a function of graphql-java-16.2. But, who knows?

That starter brought in...

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.experimental:graphql-spring-boot-starter:jar:1.0.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.graphql:spring-graphql:jar:1.0.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.graphql-java:graphql-java:jar:16.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.graphql-java:java-dataloader:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.8:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.9:compile
```

I can see it has some GraphQLScalarType...

```
    public static final GraphQLScalarType GraphQLBigDecimal = GraphQLScalarType.newScalar()
            .name("BigDecimal").description("Built-in java.math.BigDecimal").coercing(new GraphqlBigDecimalCoercing()).build();
```

... along with some deprecation that it may move someday, but its there now: https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/v16.2/src/main/java/graphql/Scalars.java#L108. I just can't figure out how to use it.

What do I have to do in my schema.graphqls file or project to get to use BigDecimal on my GraphQL Types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There it is. I needed to add it to the `RuntimeWiringBuilderCustomizer` thing...

```
@Component
public class BoaDataWiring implements RuntimeWiringBuilderCustomizer {
  private final NowService nowService;

  public BoaDataWiring(NowService nowService) {
    this.nowService = nowService;
  }

  @Override
  public void customize(RuntimeWiring.Builder builder) {
    /*
     * Declare the scalar here in the RuntimeWiring.Builder
     * Note there remains some ugly deprecation warning...
     *
     * "The is a non standard scalar and is difficult for clients 
     * (such as browser and mobile code) to cope with the exact 
     * semantics. These will be removed in the future version and 
     * moved to another library."
     */
    builder.scalar(Scalars.GraphQLBigDecimal); // <- This is what did it
    builder.type("Query", wiring ->
        wiring.dataFetcher("now", env -> nowService.now()));
  }
}
```

2021-08-25 update: On the https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#data-querydsl-customizations snapshot Spring has changed the interface to `RuntimeWiringConfigurer`. It works pretty much the same...

```
/**
 * RuntimeWiring provides access to the RuntimeWiring.Builder.
 */
@Component
public class RuntimeWiring implements RuntimeWiringConfigurer {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RuntimeWiring.class);

  @Override
  public void configure(graphql.schema.idl.RuntimeWiring.Builder builder) {
    LOG.trace("configure( builder: {} )", builder);
    builder.scalar(Scalars.GRAPHQL_DATE);
    builder.scalar(Scalars.GRAPHQL_BIG_DECIMAL);
  }
}
```

Note also that the 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT does actually come with graphql-java v17 which does, indeed, remove `Scalars.GraphQLBigDecimal`, so that `Scalars.GRAPHQL_BIG_DECIMAL` is my own.

Answer (score 0):

add following dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

//corrected type

```
type TemplateLineItemAction {
    type: String!
    quantity: BigDecimal
}
```

Comment: Hmm. The `org.springframework.experimental/graphql-spring-boot-starter` is the replacement for the `com.graphql-java/graphql-spring-boot-starter`. So I can't really bring that in without kicking what I've already got working out. I don't think I can do that. Its like something isn't "turning on" the BigDecimal mapping.

Comment: Yeah. This does end up in conflict with the `com.graphql-java/graphql-spring-boot-starter`.